# How to retrieve data from different rows of the same table based on different criteria

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle10g

I'm trying to write a plain SQL statement for building an Oracle report but I'm stuck at some point. **x_request** table stores the requests made and different tasks related to specific requests that have been done are stored in **x_request_work_log**. To summarize the structure of these tables:

**X_request**

```
-id  
-name
-requester
-request_date
```

**x_request_work_log**

```
-id
-request_id (foreign key)
-taskId
-start_date
-end_date
```

Now let's assume that these tables are filled with sample data as follows:

x_request

```
id    name      requester    request_date
1     firstReq  John         01/01/2012
2     secondReq Steve        21/01/2012
```

x_request_work_log

```
id    requestId    taskId    startDate     endDate
1     1            0         01/01/2012    03/01/2012
2     1            1         04/01/2012    04/01/2012
3     1            2         05/01/2012    15/01/2012
4     2            0         24/01/2012    02/02/2012
```

The template of my report is as follows:

```
requestName    timeSpent(task(0))    timeSpent(task(1))     timeSpent(task(2)) 
|          |   |                 |   |                |     |                |
```

So, that's where I'm stuck. I need a Sql Select statement that will return each row in the formatted way as described above.  How can i retrieve and display the start and end dates of different tasks. Btw timeSpent = endDate(task(x)) - startDate(task(x))

**Note:** Using different select subqueries for each spent time calculation is not an option due to performance constraints. There must be another way.

Comment: Depends on which version of Oracle, but the thing you are looking for is pivot query.

Comment: @Korhan Ozturk - Are the 0, 1, and 2 hard-coded values?  Or could they be any three taskId values?  Or could they be more than three taskId values?

Comment: @JustinCave taskIds refer to the 'id' field of 'Tasks' table. I'm editing the question.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson I'm using Oracle 10g.

Comment: @KorhanÖztürk - Are there always 3 `taskId` values for a request?  Might there be more?  If so, do you want more columns in the result set?  Do you always want them reported in `taskId` order?

Comment: @JustinCave - No 3 is just an arbitrary number I chose for demonstration. There are approximately 10 different tasks for each request to be processed which are stored in Tasks (id, name, ...) table.

Comment: @KorhanÖztürk - Is the number of tasks (and/or the number of columns in the report) fixed at the time that the report is written?  If reauest 1 has 9 tasks and request 2 has 11 tasks, what do you want your report to look like?

Comment: Pivot was introduced in 11g, so answer from @Justin Cave which I see you've accepted was the way to go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you just want something like

```
SELECT r.name request_name,
       SUM( (CASE WHEN l.taskId = 0 
                  THEN l.endDate - l.StartDate
                  ELSE 0
               END) ) task0_time_spent,
       SUM( (CASE WHEN l.taskId = 1 
                  THEN l.endDate - l.StartDate
                  ELSE 0
               END) ) task1_time_spent,
       SUM( (CASE WHEN l.taskId = 2 
                  THEN l.endDate - l.StartDate
                  ELSE 0
               END) ) task2_time_spent
  FROM x_request_work_log l
       JOIN x_request r ON (l.requestId = r.Id)
 GROUP BY r.name
```

If you happen to be using 11g, you could also use the PIVOT operator.

Comment: It worked (with a little modification though), thank you sir. I wonder if it's possible to replace 'case-when' statements with 'decode'. What do you think?

Comment: @KorhanÖztürk - You can certainly use `DECODE` rather than `CASE` assuming the logic is simple enough as it is in my example.  `CASE` is much more flexible, however, and strikes me as easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to display all members of a group in one row, you can accomplish this in MySQL with the `GROUP_CONCAT` operator (I don't know what the equivalent is in Oracle):

```
> SELECT requestID,
         GROUP_CONCAT(DATEDIFF(endDate,startDate)) AS length
  FROM request_work_log
  GROUP BY requestId;

+-----------+--------+
| requestID | length |
+-----------+--------+
|         1 | 2,0,10 |
|         2 | 9      |
+-----------+--------+
```

(and then add in the inner join to your other table to replace requestID with the request name)